# How to derive the sum of the following series

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sum of the series is given by:
$$\sum_{j=2}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}i^2j = \frac{1}{120}n(n^2-1)(8n^2+5n-2)$$
How to derive the above result?

Comment: Are you sure you want the exact solution? Asymptotics would be very easy ($O(n^5)$)

Comment: I also know the asymptotics of the sum. I just wonder how the exact solution is derived.

Comment: See [Faulhaber's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula#Examples).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to use induction:

- **Basis step** : for $n=2$ verify that the equality is true.
- **Induction step**: assume that:
  $$\sum_{j=2}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}i^2j = \frac{1}{120}n(n^2-1)(8n^2+5n-2)$$

so we have:
$$\sum_{j=2}^{n+1}\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}i^2j = \frac{1}{120}n(n^2-1)(8n^2+5n-2)+(n+1)\sum_{i=1}^ni^2$$

and use the identity $\sum_{i=1}^ni^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\tag{1}$

---

**Edit** without induction, using $(1)$ we have:
$$\begin{align}\sum_{j=2}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}i^2j&=\sum_{j=2}^{n}j\frac{j(j-1)(2j-1)}{6}\\ \\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{j^2(j-1)(2j-1)}{6} \\ \\
&=\frac{1}{6}\sum_{j=1}^{n}(2j^4-3j^3+j^2)\\ \\
&=\frac{1}{6}\left(2\sum_{j=1}^nj^4-3\sum_{j=1}^nj^3+\sum_{j=1}^nj^2\right) \\ \\
&=\frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{1}{15}n(n+1)(2n+1)(3n^2+3n-1)-\frac{3}{4}n^2(n+1)^2+\frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1)\right) \end{align}$$

Comment: It is easy to check by induction. However, I just want to calculate the sum without knowing the result first.

Comment: And you can manage the sum to get the result, the summation is not hideous because there are a lot of common terms

Comment: @Did I agree with your comment, in fact it maybe wrong and uneeded,

Comment: The revised version is much better.

Answer (score 0):

The second sum is over $i$, so you can 'pull out' j and solve $\sum_{i=1}^{j-1} i^2$, then solve for $j$.

Comment: Upper limit for second sum depends on j!

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^{j-1} i^2 j = j \sum_{i=1}^{j-1}i^2$